# How to handle displaying of UIAlertView iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Does `UIView` receive any events when an alert appears? Are there existing  events like `lostFocus`?

I know that it is possible to override the `show` method of the `UIAlertView`, but I wonder whether there is an approach to handle it directly from the top view of a hierarchy?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Also just in case, UIAlertView is deprecated. use UIActionController instead.

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is? Usually an alert is harmless as it appears, does its thing then returns leaving everything underneath unaffected as its an overlay. If there are issues, you should deal with them before you call `show`.

Comment: Actually there is no problem in iOS. I just write the cross-platform UI library on JS. And I trying to apply the cocoa approaches (I really like it) to my framework. So I wonder how it issue could be resolved in cocoa-touch.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do this, and it's a huge pain.

Put this in your View Controller. (`UIAlertView` was deprecated since the release of iOS 8)

```
UIAlertController *someController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"someTitle" message:@"someMessage" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *someAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"someTitle" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
    // your code here for THE ACTION
}];
[someController addAction:someAction];
[self presentViewController:someController animated:YES completion:^{
    // your code here for AFTER THE ALERT PRESENTS
}];
```

You may add as many `Actions` as you would like. Just some notes to go over:

- The `AlertController`'s `style` is either `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` if it's an `Alert Box`, or `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` if you want an `Action Sheet` from the bottom of the screen.
- The `block` for the `someAction`'s `handler` parameter needs to have the parameter `action` as a `UIAlertAction*`.
- The `completion` `block` takes **no** parameters, and is called **when the alert presents**.
- The `hanler` `block` is called when the user taps on their choice in the alert box or action sheet.

Refer to the Apple Documentation for more info about the `UIAlertController` class or the `UIAlertAction` class.

For more info about Objective-C blocks, visit [fuckingblocksyntax.com](http://www.fuckingblocksyntax.com), or its more work-friendly counterpart, [goshdarnblocksyntax.com](http://www.goshdarnblocksyntax.com).

Comment: ok, it’s good. But what if an alert spawned from an third-party lib, and there is no opportunity to change it? Something similar to `lostFocus` would be perfect for this case. But I didn’t find any similar to that :(